# Script to upload to sftp is not working

Tags: shell, sftp

I have 2 Linux boxes and i am trying to upload files from one machine to other using sftp. I have put all the commands I use in the terminal to she'll script like below.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/tests/sftptest
sftp user1@192.168.0.1
cd sftp/sftptest
put test.txt
bye
```

But this is not working and gives me error like the directory does not exist. Also, the terminal remain in >sftp,  which means bye is not executed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Most FTP clients are designed for interactive use.  The programs in the [`ncftp`](http://www.ncftpd.com/ncftp/) package were designed, as you want here, to automate FTP transfers.   I find them much easier to use.

Comment: Sir Blaster Alfred Ψ, I would strongly encourage you to look at `rsync` instead of `sftp`. It is far more flexible and capable (actively developed and brought to you by those same clever folks that write SAMBA). Create a keypair to allow passwordless ssh connections between the 2 linux boxes. The `rsync` is your Swiss-Army Knife for file transfer solution.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a [here-document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/tests/sftptest

sftp user1@192.168.0.1 <<< EOF
cd sftp/sftptest
put test.txt
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run the `sftp` command, it connects and waits for you to type commands. It kind of starts its own "subshell".

The other commands in your script would execute only once the `sftp` command finishes. And they would obviously execute as local shell commands, so particularly the `put` will fail as a non existing command.

---

You have to provide the `sftp` commands directly to `sftp` command.

One way to do that, is using an input redirection. E.g. using the "here document" as the answer by @cyrus already shows:

```
sftp username@host <<< EOF
sftp_command_1
sftp_command_2
EOF
```

Other way is using an external `sftp` script:

```
sftp username@host -b sftp.txt
```

Where, the `sftp.txt` script contains:

```
sftp_command_1
sftp_command_2
```